# Autohide marker after x seconds

Tags: leaflet, select-by-location, time, markers, circle

Working with Leaflet Control Search. I would like to add a timeout function to the marker that is added to the map if a location is found.

Any ideas in which line I have to add "setTimeout" function?

I tried

```
showLocation: function(latlng, title) { 

    if(this.options.zoom)
        this._map.setView(latlng, this.options.zoom);
        this._map.panTo(latlng);                                                       

    if(this._markerLoc)
    {
        this._markerLoc.setLatLng(latlng);  
        this._markerLoc.setTitle(title);
        this._markerLoc.show();
        this._markerLoc.bindPopup(title);
        this._markerLoc = setTimeout(function() {
        this._markerLoc.hide()
        },1000);
        if(this.options.animateLocation)
            this._markerLoc.animate();

    }

    if(this.options.autoCollapse)
        this.collapse();
    return this;
}});
```

The result: marker still shows up...

Comment: Please post some of your Leaflet code to show what you have tried, and what isn't working as expected.  An image might help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something along the lines of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), e.g.

```
setTimeout(function() {
        // hide marker
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Just a short advice: not remove marker but marker.hide() is correct.